# Why does GCC not warn for unreachable code?

Tags: c, gcc, static-variables, gcc-warning

Why doesn't GCC (4.6.3) give me any warning for the *unreachable code* in the below example?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int status(void)
{
    static int first_time = 1;

    if (first_time) {
        return 1;
        first_time = 0; /* Never reached */
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    printf("first call %d\n", status());
    printf("second call %d\n", status());
    return 0;
}
```

Note, the purpose of the faulty `status()` function was to maintain a status. I had expected to get a warning for this with [-Wall](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wall). I tried also [-Wunreachable-code](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.7/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wunreachable_002dcode-437), [-Wextra](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wextra), [-pedantic](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-pedantic-1), and [-ansi](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#index-ANSI-support) (as it was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730255/gcc-shouldnt-a-warning-be-issued)). Yet, none of those give me a warning.

It appears GCC silently removes the static variable assignment.

In my opinion, GCC options [-Wall](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wall) [-Werror](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Werror) should throw an error.

Answer (score 29):

GCC 4.4 will give you a warning. In the later versions of GCC, this feature ([-Wunreachable-code](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.7/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wunreachable_002dcode-437)) has been removed.

See *[Re: gcc -Wunreachable-code option](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2011-05/msg00360.html)*

> The `-Wunreachable-code` has been removed, because it was unstable: it
> relied on the optimizer, and so different versions of gcc would warn
> about different code.  The compiler still accepts and ignores the
> command line option so that existing Makefiles are not broken.  In
> some future release the option will be removed entirely.

Comment: I hate it when they remove features based on reasons like that. And doing it covertly... *"The compiler still accepts and ignores the
command line option"*

So after a compiler update we had a bug, that could have been avoided if the compiler had warned...

Comment: Commit [bc3c12a29c67753c473b465767b2ba6b2f7e72a6](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=commit;h=bc3c12a29c67753c473b465767b2ba6b2f7e72a6) if anyone is curious.

Answer (score 2):

#### A smaller set of non-broken unreachable code warnings making it back to GCC?

The following bug report

- [Bug 46476](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46476) - Missing Warning about unreachable code after return [-Wunreachable-code-return]

Has been tracking ongoing work (albeit slow) of bringing back a smaller set of unreachable code warnings in GCC implemented at [GIMPLE lowering time](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/gimplebackend), focusing on avoiding the aggressiveness of [the original feature](https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc-patches/2009-11/msg00179.html) (*"-Wunreachable-code is seriously broken, I suggest to remove its implementation completely."*):

> **Richard Biener 2021-11-29 14:29:49 UTC**
>
> `-Wunreachable-code-ctrl` at GIMPLE lowering time
>
> This is the `-Wunreachable-code-ctrl` (not enabled by -Wextra) patch
> diagnosing unreachable stmts after a break, continue, goto (or loops
> without exit via the backedge goto).
>
> Note that unlike clang which seems to model the option names after
> what kind of stmt is detected as unreachable these patches model the
> option names after what kind of stmt makes other stmts unreachable.
> Not sure what is more useful in practice [to avoid coding-style
> issues].

However, it been one year since the last update of the ticket.

Answer (score 1):

gcc has dozens of passes -- to see them try compiling with switches like

-da -dAp -Wa,-a -fdump-ipa-all-all -fdump-tree-all-all -fdump-rtl-all-all

My guess is that some pass has done dead-code elimination before the pass designated to issue the warning in question. Which could reasonably be considered a bug, but likely the gcc team regard the warning more as a convenience than a moral commitment, and aren't motivated to do a lot of work to make it precise and complete.  If you want to contribute, you could disable optimization passes one-by-one until you find the one preventing the warning, then file a bug report documenting the problem.  If that isn't worth your time, maybe fixing it isn't worth their time. :-)

Comment: Re *"-fdump-rtl-all-all"*: Not just *"[-fdump-rtl-all](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html#index-fdump-rtl-all)"*? (same as "-da"). For what version of GCC?

Comment: Does "-dAp" work? Should it be the separate "[-dA](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html#index-dA) [-dp](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html#index-dp)"? For what version of GCC?

Comment: E.g., the OP has left the building: *"Last seen more than 9 years ago"*. Perhaps somebody else can chime in?