# Code after return statement without warning

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-warnings, dead-code

We just found an issue in our code base, where a statement is after a return statement.

e.g.

```
std::string MyClass::addElement(Type1 &item, const std::string &param2)
{
    if (param2.empty())
    {
        // logging
        return "";
    }

    return m_database->addElement(item, param2, item.status, true);

    // here I would expect an unreachable code warning
    m_database->updateTableA(item.p1, item.p2, item.p3, AType::AType23);
}
```

What I don't understand, why our compiler (GCC 4.8.5 and 7) does not emit a warning?

We compile with `-std=c++0x -Wall -Wextra -Wsign-compare -Wunknown-pragmas -Wold-style-cast -Wshadow -Wfatal-errors`

Comment: I guess it must be a compile time error. BTW why don't you update your GCC, current version is 8.2

Comment: [-Wunreachable-code warning removed](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2011-05/msg00360.html)

Comment: @VTT thanks for the info. So are there any compilers/tools, which check this? We also use cppcheck and clang-tidy, but both didn't warn either

Comment: @VictorGubin Switching to different gcc version (especially when dealing with outdated systems) is not trivial.

Comment: @VictorGubin GCC 4.8.5 is most current on CentOS 7.

Comment: VC++ issues `warning C4702: unreachable code`

Comment: Currently not an option, because this code base is for Linux only and won't compile with VC++.

Comment: @Simon have you tried  https://jdhao.github.io/2017/09/04/install-gcc-newer-version-on-centos/ ?

Comment: Sightly OT now: we are currently testing https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-7/, but not yet in an operational fashion. But GCC 7.2 doesn't check that issue either.

Comment: BTW, there is another option with [RPM Fusion](https://rpmfusion.org/)

Comment: @VictorGubin That is not even half of the story, horror parts about fighting incompatibilities arising from mixing different binaries / runtimes, building abi bridges, creating statically linked jumbo executables or setting up isolation are missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GCC *cannot* emit a warning for dead code, since the `Wunreachable-code` flag/feature is removed after version 4.4, as you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17249934/gcc-does-not-warn-for-unreachable-code).

Clang version 4 (head is 8 out now, so I don't suggest it), will also emit a warning, when the code is compiled with the `[-Wunreachable-code` flag:

> warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]

---

You could try a static analysis tool, there are plenty of them in that [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#C,_C++).

Comment: Isn't cppcheck already dead and scan-build a part of llvm / clang?

Comment: @VTT haven't used one for a long time, answer updated, thank you for the comment and the upvote!

Comment: I ended up adding an additional Clang compliation step to our build server.