# valgrind showing memory leaks. how do i stop the leak?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

I'm new to valgrind and I ran it with some code I wrote for a quadtree.

I've written a function that recursively frees the Nodes from the quadtree:

```
void destroyTree (Node* p)
{
    if (!p) return;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        destroyTree(p->child[i]);

    free(p);
}
```

I call that function in the main function:

```
int main( int argc, char **argv ) {

  Node *head;

  // make the head node
  head = makeNode( 0.0,0.0, 0 );

  // make a tree
  makeChildren( head );
  makeChildren( head->child[0] );
  makeChildren( head->child[1] );
  makeChildren( head->child[2] );
  makeChildren( head->child[3] );

  // print the tree for Gnuplot
    writeTree( head );
  return 0;

  //destroy tree
  destroyTree (head);
  return 0;
}
```

When I run valgrind its showing that I lose some memory.

The structure is:

```
struct qnode {
  int level;
  double xy[2];
  struct qnode *child[4];
};
typedef struct qnode Node;
```

I call malloc in buildTree:

```
Node *makeNode( double x, double y, int level ) {

  int i;

  Node *node = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));

  node->level = level;

  node->xy[0] = x;
  node->xy[1] = y;

  for( i=0;i<4;++i )
    node->child[i] = NULL;

  return node;
}
```

How do I stop the leak? Is there something wrong with my freeing function or is it somewhere else?

[image: valgrind memory leak]

Comment: It says a `malloc` call in `makenode` is unfreed. You should share that function.

Comment: @StoryTeller I've added the code where I use malloc above

Comment: you're using `return 0` in the middle of your code so destroy function isn't called!! please enable warnings

Comment: In `makenode`, you have a member variable called `xy` that appears to be either an array or pointer. How are you allocating space for that, and likewise, how are you freeing it? Before you free a node, you also have to free any pointers inside of it, first.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I tried removing the `return 0` but that didn't make a difference

Comment: Please post your definition of `Node`.

Comment: there are 2 return statements. Then please remove the one in the middle, that should fix it. Else [edit] your question

Comment: `makeChildren` what does it do?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre that fixed it! thanks!

Comment: Your code don’t compile as you have unreachable vode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, since noone spotted this, the end of `main` reads:

```
  // print the tree for Gnuplot
    writeTree( head );
  return 0;    // <----------- wooooot!

  //destroy tree
  destroyTree (head);
  return 0;
}
```

We notice that the 2 last lines are unreacheable because there's a `return 0` statement just above this. So the `destroyTree` method is never called, which explains the memory leak.

*Always enable compiler warnings and read them*. The control flow is simple enough, every compiler detects dead code here.

That said, even `-Wall -Wextra` doesn't work here, the `-Wunreachable-code` flag must be added explicitly ([Why does GCC not warn for unreachable code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17249934/why-does-gcc-not-warn-for-unreachable-code))

Comment: How do I enable compiler warnings?

Comment: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. In that case, surprisingly it doesn't work!!

Comment: Is it okay to keep the `return 0` underneath `destroyTree (head);` ?

Comment: yes. C99 now considers that implied, but you can leave it.