# Java int equality inconsistency?

Tags: java, syntax, processing, conditional-statements

This is driving me insane because it completely violates my attempts to de-buggify it:

```
int k = keyCode; //keyCode being a variable declared by a keyPress
//in the Processing library
//k and keyCode are working properly.
if ((k - UP)*500 == 0); //int UP=38;
{
 println((k-UP)*500 == 0);
 //some other code here
}
```

The result? "false" (and by removing the '== 0', a number that isn't 0).
As far as I know only when you use the arrow keys (k==37,38,39,40; 38 being UP) make this condition true.

Is there any such inconsistency, and what may cause it?
(The strange format of the condition is because it fixed a similar problem with the RIGHT key not working correctly with just   k==RIGHT).

Comment: Remove the ; at the end of the if statement

Comment: IntelliJ would warn you about the empty body of if

Comment: This is why braces belong on the end of the line with the if!

Comment: Wouldn't really help.  I've seen this exact same error with Egyptian braces.

Comment: I'll close this out, as the issue was quite simple and rather unrelated. +1 for the honesty. BTW, [same problem, different language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851162/can-gcc-accurately-catch-useless-conditionals), it happens to all of us.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a semicolon after `if`, so `println` is always executed.

Comment: Wow, I feel really stupid right now.

Comment: @BlueShamen Don't worry, we all do at times. +1 for the honesty.

Answer (score 5):

You had a `;` after your if. That makes it an if with an empty statment, followed by an unconditiend block. Just remove the semicolon in the if line.