# Detecting semicolon after loop/if brackets

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-construction, clang

Is there any flag in GCC (like `-Wempty-body` in clang), that could help me detect semicolons after the braces of while/for loops? Sometimes it is very hard for humans to find these simple mistakes.

```
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i);
{
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

I use GCC 4.7.3 and clang 3.2-1~exp9ubuntu1.

Edited:
I also check if compilers could help me find these mistakes after "if-else statements".

```
if (i == 0)
{
    cout << i << endl;
}
else;
{
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

What is interesting gcc is more helpful than clang (with this flags (`-Wall -pedantic -Wempty-body`) by printing warning:

```
main.cpp:30:9: warning: suggest braces around empty body in an ‘else’ statement [-Wempty-body]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can gcc accurately catch useless conditionals?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851162/can-gcc-accurately-catch-useless-conditionals)

Comment: On second thoughts, that's not a duplicate, apologies.  However, isn't `-Wempty-body` also a GCC flag?

Comment: This seems to me a very good reason (i.e. other than style) to put starting `{` on the same line as the `if`/`for`/`while` etc. And to have one-liners on the same line as well.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth The GCC flag doesn't cover empty for or while loop. From [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) `Warn if an empty body occurs in an ‘if’, ‘else’ or ‘do while’ statement. This warning is also enabled by -Wextra. `

Comment: I started writing an answer before I'd done full research, but it seems like the statement "like `-Wempty-body` in clang" is a bit misleading. Neither of my versions of g++ (4.6.3) or clang++ (2.9) gives a warning when using `-Wempty-body`.

Comment: The loop body is not empty, it is `++i;`

Comment: @BenVoigt: "Bastardizing" the for-statement to not have `++i`, but instead doing ` for (i = 0; i++ < 10;);` [yes, I know, it doesn't do  the same thing any longer- but this was just to test if it "works"] still doesn't give any warning.

Comment: Apparently there were too many false positives, and people started arguing how to make presence of a comment or macro (expanding to nothing) inhibit the warning, and at that point the whole idea was just scrapped.  http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2008-11/msg00361.html

Comment: @MatsPetersson I'm using `Ubuntu clang version 3.2-1~exp9ubuntu1 (tags/RELEASE_32/final) (based on LLVM 3.2)`.

Comment: @Kninnug Everything is good until you make simple mistake. There is flag in gcc `-Weffc++` that help you check style guidelines based on Scott Meyers Effective C++. I would be good if compilers similarly could help me with this `;` and suggest to use empty brackets.

Answer (score 2):

try

> $gcc -Wempty-body foo.c

or

> gcc -Wextra -c foo.c

Comment: This doesn't work for gcc/g++ 4.7.2 (or at least on my computer it doesn't)

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer here is "compile your code with clang++" (although my 2.9 version for x86-64 doesn't seem to catch this particular problem, just like gcc 4.6.3 doesn't catch it - so I'm not entirely convinced the original premise of the question is valid).

This particular code can avoid this problem by using the form, by giving an error for using `i` after the `for`-loop itself:

```
for(int i = ...)
```

instead of

```
int i;
for(i = ...)
```

Of course, that doesn't work in the case where you want `i` to have a value after the loop.

[And yes, it's a very annoying error - I've spent several hours staring at the screen to find this sort of bug at times - other times you spot it immediately!]