# "using namespace" in c++ headers

Tags: c++, namespaces, header-files

In all our c++ courses, all the teachers always put `using namespace std;` right after the `#include`s in their `.h` files. This seems to me to be dangerous since then by including that header in another program I will get the namespace imported into my program, maybe without realizing, intending or wanting it (header inclusion can be very deeply nested).

So my question is double: Am I right that `using namespace` should not be used in header files, and/or is there some way to undo it, something like:

```
//header.h
using namespace std {
.
.
.
}
```

One more question along the same lines: Should a header file `#include` all the headers that it's corresponding `.cpp` file needs, only those that are needed for the header definitions and let the `.cpp` file `#include` the rest, or none and declare everything it needs as `extern`?
The reasoning behind the question is the same as above: I don't want surprises when including `.h` files.

Also, if I am right, is this a common mistake? I mean in real-world programming and in "real" projects out there.

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265039/using-std-namespace

Comment: as a side note, if you get name collisions due to `using namespace` statements then you could use the fully qualified name to solve the problem.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

You should definitely NOT use `using namespace` in headers for precisely the reason you say, that it can unexpectedly change the meaning of code in any other files that include that header. There's no way to undo a `using namespace` which is another reason it's so dangerous. I typically just use `grep` or the like to make sure that `using namespace` isn't being called out in headers rather than trying anything more complicated. Probably static code checkers flag this too.

The header should include just the headers that it needs to compile. An easy way to enforce this is to always include each source file's own header as the first thing, before any other headers. Then the source file will fail to compile if the header isn't self-contained. In some cases, for example referring to implementation-detail classes within a library, you can use forward declarations instead of `#include` because you have full control over the definition of such forward declared class.

I'm not sure I would call it common, but it definitely shows up once in a while, usually written by new programmers that aren't aware of the negative consequences. Typically just a little education about the risks takes care of any issues since it's relatively simple to fix.

Comment: are we free to use `using` statements in our `.cpp` files? the `3rdPartyLib::BigClassName<3rdPartyLib::AnotherBigName,3rdPartyLib::AnotherBigName>::Iterator`s are death to the fingertips.

Comment: and how should we streamline the `template` functions--which are supposed to be in the headers? `typedefs`?

Comment: @donlan, it seems you got no response for quite a while... Yes, you can use `using` statements within `.cpp` files without much concern because the scope will be limited to just that file, but never do it before an `#include` statement. As for template functions defined in headers, unfortunately I don't know of a good solution other than just writing out the namespace... Perhaps you could put a `using` declaration within a separate scope `{ /* using statement in between brackets */ }`, that would at least prevent it from escaping the current file.

Answer (score 37):

Item 59 in Sutter and Alexandrescu's ["C++ Coding Standards: 101 Rules, Guidelines, and Best Practices"](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/c++cs.htm):

> **59. Don’t write namespace usings in a header file or before an #include.**
>
> Namespace `using`s are for your convenience, not for you to inflict on others: Never write a `using` declaration or a `using` directive before an `#include` directive.
>
> Corollary: In header files, don't write namespace-level `using` directives or `using` declarations; instead, explicitly namespace-qualify all names.

A header file is a guest in one or more source files. A header file that includes `using` directives and declarations brings its rowdy buddies over too.

A `using` *declaration* brings in one buddy. A `using` *directive* brings in all the buddies in the namespace. Your teachers' use of `using namespace std;` is a using directive.

More seriously, we have namespaces to avoid name clash. A header file is intended to provide an interface. Most headers are agnostic of what code may include them, now or in the future. Adding `using` statements for internal convenience within the header foists those convenient names on all the potential clients of that header. That can lead to name clash. And it's just plain rude.

Answer (score 13):

You need to be careful when including headers inside of headers. In large projects, it can create a very tangled dependency chain that triggers larger/longer rebuilds than were actually necessary. Check out [this article](http://gamesfromwithin.com/physical-structure-and-c-part-1-a-first-look) and [its follow-up](http://gamesfromwithin.com/physical-structure-and-c-part-2-build-times) to learn more about the importance of good physical structure in C++ projects.

You should only include headers inside a header when absolutely needed (whenever the full definition of a class is needed), and use forward declaration wherever you can (when the class is required is a pointer or a reference).

As for namespaces, I tend to use the explicit namespace scoping in my header files, and only put a `using namespace` in my cpp files.

Comment: how do you streamline `template` function declaration? that has to occur in the header, no?

Answer (score 11):

With regards to "Is there some way to undo [a `using` declaration]?"

I think it is useful to point out that `using` declarations are affected by scope.

```
#include <vector>

{   // begin a new scope with {
    using namespace std;
    vector myVector;  // std::vector is used
}   // end the scope with }

vector myOtherVector;   // error vector undefined
std::vector mySTDVector // no error std::vector is fully qualified
```

So effectively yes. By limiting the scope of the `using` declaration its effect only lasts within that scope; it is 'undone' when that scope ends.

When the `using` declaration is declared in a file outside of any other scope it has file-scope and affects everything in that file.

In the case of a header file, if the `using` declaration is at file-scope this will extend to the scope of any file the header is included in.

Comment: you seem to be the only one how understood the actual question... however, my compile is not very happy about me using inside the class deceleration.

Comment: This answer could be made even better by explaining the problem with the OP's idea of how scope should work (like the `namespace` declaration stuff) vs. how it actually works (like a variable).  `{}` enclsing it limit its scope, `{}` after it do nothing relating to it.  That is an accidental way that the `using namespace` gets applied globally.

Answer (score 7):

Check out the Goddard Space Flight Center coding standards (for C and C++).  That turns out to be a bit harder than it used to be - see the updated answers to the SO questions:

- [Should I use #include in headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804486/should-i-use-include-in-headers)
- [Self-sufficient headers in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892043/self-sufficient-header-files-in-c-c)

The GSFC C++ coding standard says:

> §3.3.7 Each header file shall `#include` the files it needs to compile, rather than forcing users to `#include` the needed files. `#includes` shall be limited to what the header needs; other `#includes` should be placed in the source file.

The first of the cross-referenced questions now includes a quote from the GSFC C coding standard, and the rationale, but the substance ends up being the same.

Answer (score 5):

You are right that `using namespace` in header is dangerous.
I do not know a way how to undo it.
It is easy to detect it however just search for `using namespace` in header files.
For that last reason it is uncommon in real projects. More experienced coworkers will soon complain if someone does something like it.

In real projects people try to minimize the amount of included files, because the less you include the quicker it compiles. That saves time of everybody.  However if the header file assumes that something should be included before it then it should include it itself. Otherwise it makes headers not self-contained.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you can use 'using' in C++ headers safely if you write your declarations in a nested namespace like this:

```
namespace DECLARATIONS_WITH_NAMESPACES_USED_INCLUDED
{
    /*using statements*/

    namespace DECLARATIONS_WITH_NO_NAMESPACES_USED_INCLUDED
    {
        /*declarations*/
    }
}

using namespace DECLARATIONS_WITH_NAMESPACES_USED_INCLUDED::DECLARATIONS_WITH_NO_NAMESPACES_USED_INCLUDED;
```

This should include only the things declared in 'DECLARATIONS_WITH_NO_NAMESPACES_USED_INCLUDED' without the namespaces used. I have tested it on mingw64 compiler.

Comment: This is a useful technique I hadn't seen before; thanks.  Normally I've been fine with using full scope qualification, and putting `using` declarations inside function definitions where I can so they won't pollute namespaces outside the function.  But now I'm wanting to use C++11 user-defined literals in a header file, and per the usual convention, the literal operators are protected by a namespace; but I wan't to use them in constructor initializer lists that aren't in a scope that I can use a non-polluting `using` declaration.  So this is great for solving that problem.

Comment: Although an unfortunate side effect of this pattern is that any classes declared inside the innermost namespace will show up in compiler error messages with the fully qualified name: `error: ... DECLARATIONS_WITH_NAMESPACES_USED_INCLUDED:: DECLARATIONS_WITH_NO_NAMESPACES_USED_INCLUDED::ClassName ...`.  At least, that's what's happening for me in g++.

Answer (score 4):

You are right. And any file should only include the headers needed by that file. As for "is doing things wrong common in real world projects?" - oh, yes!

Answer (score 4):

Like all things in programming, pragmatism should win over dogmatism, IMO.

So long as you make the decision project-wide ("Our project uses STL extensively, and we don't want to have to prepend everything with std::."), I don't see the problem with it.  The only thing you're risking is name collisions, after all, and with the ubiquity of STL it's unlikely to be a problem.

On the other hand, if it was a decision by one developer in a single (non-private) header-file, I can see how it would generate confusion among the team and should be avoided.