# undefined reference to Class::method C++

Tags: c++, reference

I got a problem compiling the source that follows:

```
    QString code = this->viewManager()->activeView()->document()->text();
    Qualifier qua;
    qua.setQCode(code);
```

It tells me that

```
error: undefined reference to `Qualifier::setQCode(QString)'
```

the code of the qualifier.h and .cpp follows

```
#ifndef __QUALIFIER_H__
#define __QUALIFIER_H__

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <QString>
#include <queue>
#include "analyser.h"



using namespace std;



class Qualifier
{

private:

    string code;
    queue<method> tokenisedCode;
    //queue<analysis> analysedCode;

void tokeniseCode();

public :


void setCode(string code);

void setQCode(QString code);

void computeLocAnalysis();

void computeCCAnalysis();

void visualiseResults();


};

 #endif /* __QUALIFIER_H__ */
```

and the CPP is

```
#include "qualifier.h"

using namespace std;


void Qualifier::tokeniseCode()
{

Parser par;
par.setCode(code);
par.parse();
this->tokenisedCode = par.getMethods();

}

void Qualifier::setCode(string code)
{
    this->code = code;
}

void Qualifier::setQCode(QString code)
{
this->code = qPrintable(code);
}

void Qualifier::computeLocAnalysis()
{

std::cout << this->code << std::endl;

/*
locAnalyser ana = new locAnalyser();
ana.setMethodList(tokenisedCode);
ana.computeResult();
this->analysedCode = ana.getResult();
*/
 }

void Qualifier::computeCCAnalysis()
{

// To be implemented;

 }

void Qualifier::visualiseResults()
{
/*
//Need a grapher of the results
while(!analysedCode.empty())
{
    analysis meth = analysedCode.front();
    cout << "LOC: " << meth.result << "\t\t" << meth.name << endl;
    analysedCode.pop();
    cout << "------------------------------------" << endl;
}
*/
}
```

I do not understand why the reference is not seen! I mean, is the exact thing, the same way that is done in the rest of the project!

Comment: Do you get the same error for `tokeniseCode()`? If so, your cpp file probably isn't being seen.

Comment: [Never use `using namespace ...` in a header file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849457/using-namespace-in-c-headers).

Comment: Yes, every method of the object Qualifier that I am going to use, generates the same error: undefined reference Qualifier::name_method.

Comment: Does "and so on" include the definition of the method the compiler is complaining about? if so, you should probably include it to avoid confusion.

Comment: I've eliminated the namespace in the header file. No changes, same error.

Comment: it includes the methods' implementation of the declarations in the header file...

Comment: well, obviously not, because the compiler is complaining, so please post some code that reproduces the error.

Comment: Sorry, I've cut half of the code without see that the setQCode was not there.

Answer (score 6):

According to the header file you have 2 different implementations of similar functions:

```
void setCode(string code);

void setQCode(QString code);
```

But in the .cpp you only implement the first:

```
void Qualifier::setCode(string code)
{
    this->code = code;
}
```

Therefore the compiler complains about the missing `setQCode()`.

**Solution**: either implement it or remove it's definition from the header file.

Comment: done. there was the implementation, just it was not in this post. Now there is and the problem persists....

Comment: How many source files do you have in this project? It may be simply that they are not being linked appropriately.

Comment: It is an open source project, Kate of KDE. I must add a feature, thus I simple added a folder in the project and the added files

Comment: It seems you need to edit the configuration files that are used to build the project and add the filenames of the sources you created :)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show us yout implementation of Qualifier::setQCode(QString) in .cpp file.

Maybe the argument from implementation cpp file does not match the argument of prototype from header file.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 functions

```
void setCode(string code);

void setQCode(QString code);
```

May you've forgotten to implement setQCode??

Answer (score 0):

This is reported by linker, isn't it? I looks like the particular translation unit or library containing definition of 'Qualifier' class is not included in linking process.