# C++: getline not part of argument list

Tags: c++, getline

I'm fairly new to C++, sorry if my questions aren't quite specific enough. Here goes.

I'm trying to overload the `>>` operator for a class which I have called "book."
"Book" contains 'title,' 'author,' and 'publisher' string objects, a 'student count' int, and a 'price' double variable. Part of my assignment is to take these values from a provided .txt file and load values into their corresponding variables/objects. All values are on their own lines within the .txt file, and they each follow this format:

> ```
>  //Title, Author, Publisher, Price
>
> Starting Out with Java 
> Gaddis  
> Scott/Jones
> 105.99
> ```

I try to use `getline()` to take the string values (I use a temp string after I take the price double), but when I type it in, Visual Studio says:

> Error: no intsance of overloaded function 'getline' matches the argument list.

I don't understand this. I included both `<iostream>` and `<string>`, which I believe are both required for `getline` to work. I'm working on getting the class file down before moving to the main code, so I apologize for not having a main code to post. Here's the .cpp file for class book:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "book.h"

using namespace std;

book::book()
{
}

book::~book()
{
}

istream& operator>> (istream &in, book &bookInfo) {
    string temp;
    getline(in, bookInfo.title);
    return in;
}
```

There's question number 1 down...

Assuming I can get `getline` to work, I have another problem.
Visual Studio says that `bookInfo.title` is inaccessible, even though this is the accompanying .cpp file to the class. I even have the `istream&` function listed as a friend function in the class itself:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class book {
    friend istream& operator>> (istream&, book&);

public:
    book();
    virtual ~book();

private:
    string title;
    string author;
    string publisher;
    double price;
};
```

It should be noted that I used much the same syntax for another class, and was given no error messages.

Thanks for a very quick reply.

Comment: "Thanks for a very quick reply." I like it :)

Comment: book.title is a private member - you can't access it outside of the book class

Comment: @StevieG: he's declared `istream& operator>> (istream&, book&);` as a `friend`.

Comment: just make the operator a member? Your second problem could be the cause of the first..

Comment: Gives me an error message without the friend specification. Something about 'too many parameters'

Comment: @KarthikT: it doesn't work as a member function because then the left-hand argument would be a `book`, not an `std::istream`. If you make it a member function, you can only provide one argument (the right hand argument).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your header, you're not using `std::`. Fix that:

```
class book
{

    friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream&, book&);

public:

    book();

    virtual ~book();

private:

    std::string title;
    std::string author;
    std::string publisher;
    double price;

};
```

Comment: doesn't 'using namespace std' cover that?\

Comment: except I don't have that in there,,,

Comment: @Will: Not in the header file. It does in the source file, however. If you put `using namespace std;` in your header it would cover that, but that's a *horrible* practice. Never put a global `using namespace ...;` in a header; so you have to prefix with `std::` in the header.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind about horrible practice. this is for an assignment, and I guess the professor hasn't weened us off that yet. Why is it horrible exactly?

Comment: @Will: Here's a few decent reads: ["using namespace" in c++ headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849457/using-namespace-in-c-headers) and [Why is 'using namespace std;' considered a bad practice in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c). Feel free to ask more if it's not clear after reading these.

Comment: @Will: Also, [a limited-scope `using namespace ...`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1455227/1287251) is much preferred over a global `using namespace ...`. Some people still hate the limited-scope `using namespace ...`, but it's certainly less evil then a global one.

Answer (score -1):

getline is a method of std::istream class, see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/):

```
istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n );
istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n, char delim );
```

You should call it on class instance e.g.

```
your_input_stream.getline( your_params ... )
```