# invalid use of template-name Queue without an argument list

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm getting a compile error that I can't figure out. It says:

Queue.h:18:23: error: invalid use of template-name â€˜Queueâ€™ without an argument list
Queue.h:23:23: error: invalid use of template-name â€˜Queueâ€™ without an argument list

Can anyone help?

```
#if !defined QUEUE_SIZE
#define QUEUE_SIZE 30
#endif
using namespace std;

template <class TYPE> class Queue
{
 private:
  TYPE *array;
 public:
  Queue(Queue& other);
  Queue();
  ~Queue();
  Queue& operator=(Queue other);
  TYPE pushAndPop(TYPE x);
};

template <class TYPE> Queue::Queue()
{
  array=new TYPE[size];
}

template <class TYPE> Queue::~Queue()
{
  delete [] array;
}
```

Comment: You need to write `Queue<TYPE>::Queue` in the definition of the constructor. Similar for the destructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is slightly off. You need:

```
template <class TYPE> Queue<TYPE>::Queue()
{
...
}

template <TYPE>
Queue<TYPE>& operator=(Queue<TYPE> other) { ... }
```

Although note that you probably should be passing by const reference in most cases (certainly not by non-const reference):

```
template <TYPE>
Queue<TYPE>& operator=(const Queue<TYPE>& other) { ... }
```

Alternatively, you can inline the implementations:

```
template <class TYPE> class Queue
{
 private:
  TYPE *array;
 public:
  Queue(Queue& other);
  Queue() { array = new TYPE[size];}
  ~Queue() { delete [] array; }
  Queue& operator=(Queue other) { .... }
  TYPE pushAndPop(TYPE x) { .... }
};
```

Also, it is [not a good idea to put `using namespace std` in a header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849457/using-namespace-in-c-headers). In fact, it is [not really a good idea to put it anywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).