# Why does this header file not get processed properly?

Tags: c++, header-files

I have a file, in which I include a header file. However on compilation I am getting lots of `was not declared in this scope` errors, which is odd as I declare/include everything I need in the header file. Here is the header file

```
#ifndef INPUT_H
#define INPUT_H
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
using namespace std;
multimap <SDL_EventType, function<void(SDL_Event&)>> functions;

template <typename T>
void registerInput(SDL_EventType type, T&& functionPointer);
#endif
```

And here is the source file:

```
#include "input.h"
template <typename T>
void registerInput(SDL_EventType type, T&& functionPointer){
    functions.insert(pair<SDL_EventType, function<void(SDL_Event&)> >(type, functionPointer));
}
```

The compile error:

```
input.cpp:3:20: error: ‘SDL_EventType’ was not declared in this scope.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show the compile errors.

Comment: @DanielDaranas input.cpp:3:20: error: ‘SDL_EventType’ was not declared in this scope. Which is odd because SDL_EventTYpe is declared in SDL/SDL.h which I include in input.h

Comment: and no "using namespace" in a header!

Comment: @alexbuisson Ah, I didn't know that was a bad idea, I'll remove it.

Comment: @alexbuisson Out of interest why is it a bad idea?

Comment: Won't solve the problem, but I think you need to put the definition of `registerInput` in the header file, or you won't be able to call it, since it's a template function, and template functions are only instantiated when they are called (by most compilers at least).

Comment: @handuel, Agree it's not the "Answer" to the question, that's why it's just a comment, but before saying "Out of interest " Ask Google or read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849457/using-namespace-in-c-headers to known why it's not a good idea to put 'using namespace' in header file!

Comment: @alexbuisson "Out of interest" does not mean "This has no interest". It means "I'm asking because I'm interested in this subject."

Comment: DanielDaranas Thank you, Sorry @handuel, I'm not enough skilled in English and sometime I misunderstand.

Comment: @alexbuisson It is fine. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Thankyou, that helps with this issue, however, as you stated, the problem still remains with other functions etc.

Comment: For some reason the file is not included! I added tons of errors to the header, and they aren't picked up, the compiler doesn't process them.

Comment: Got it! I accidentally had a precompiled version of the header in the directory.

Comment: precompiled headers - I turn it off whenever possible!

Comment: @MatsPetersson It was from a mistyped compilation command.