# C++ macro integers and object definitions

Tags: c++, macros, header, definition

I lack of experience with C++ and I am trying to create a Settings file to put all my definitions and global variables there, so my project's classes can access those the values from there. The Settings.h file could look like this:

```
#ifndef SETTINGS_H_
#define SETTINGS_H_

#define COLOR_BLUE = Vec3b(255, 0, 0);
#define COLOR_GREEN = Vec3b(0, 255, 0);
#define NOT_SET = 0;
#define IN_PROCESS = 1;
#define SET = 2;
#define FGD_PX = 255;
#define BGD_PX = 127;

#include <cv.h>
using namespace cv;

class Settings {
};
#endif /* SETTINGS_H_ */
```

The idea is to access the variables without instantiate the class but just including it.

Is there any beautiful way to do this?

cheers,

Comment: How about omitting that `=`...

Comment: Don't put `using namespace ...` directives in header files. Never. Under no circumstances.

Comment: `#define` 's have global scope and are not type safe. best to use `static const`

Comment: why shouldn't I use namespace in header files, [Oswald](http://stackoverflow.com/users/534124/oswald)?

Comment: [“using namespace” in c++ headers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5849668/2176127)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <cv.h>
using namespace cv;

#ifndef SETTINGS_H_
#define SETTINGS_H_

#define COLOR_BLUE Vec3b(255, 0, 0)
#define COLOR_GREEN Vec3b(0, 255, 0)
#define NOT_SET 0
#define IN_PROCESS 1
#define SET 2
#define FGD_PX 255
#define BGD_PX 127

class Settings {
public:
   static int var1;
   static float var2;
   static short var3;
};

// initialization
int Settings::var1 = SET;
float Settings::var2 = 3.14;
short Settings::var3 = BGD_PX;

#endif /* SETTINGS_H_ */
```

Usage:

```
int tmp = Settings::var1;
```

Comment: Of course you don't want those static definitions in the header.

Comment: As of c++11 you can initialize them directly in the declaration.

Comment: The `using namespace` declaration should **never** be in a header file.

Answer (score 2):

Constants either go in enums, or as static consts.  Manifest constants generally are reserved for compiler type options:

```
#ifndef SETTINGS_H_
#define SETTINGS_H_

class Settings {
public:
   static const vec3b color_blue;
   static const vec3b color_green;
   enum statics {
         NOT_SET = 0,
         IN_PROCESS = 1,
         SET = 2,
         FGD_PX = 255,
         BGD_PX = 127
   };

};

vec3b Settings::color_blue(255, 0, 0);
vec3b Settings::color_green(0, 255, 0);

#include <cv.h>

#endif
```

Comment: And once again: As of c++11 you can initialize member variables in the declaration.

Comment: @user2176127 I was so excited to remove all the manifest constants, I didnt want to have to worry about portability

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have equals signs or semicolons with #defines.  What do you plan on putting in your Settings class?

Comment: To comment, use `add comment` under the question. This area is only for answers. Please delete this post.

Comment: @Desolator You need a certain amount of reputation in order to post comments.