# c++ constant reference return declaration of operator = as non function

Tags: c++

Please tell what I am doing wrong in this code below, compilor is giving me following error
1. declaration of operator = as non function
2. expected primary expression before const
I am not able to identify my mistake

and so on
plz help me

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class myClass{

    int a;
    int b;

    public:

        myClass();
        myClass(int x, int y);
        const myClass& operator=(const myClass &);  
        void display();     

};


myClass::myClass(){

    a=0;
    b=0;
}
myClass::myClass(int x, int y){
    this->a=x;
    this->b=y;
}

const myClass& myClass::operator=(const class & rightobj){

    if(this!=&rightobj){

        this->a=rightobj.a;
        this->b=rightobj.b;

    }

    return *this;

}

void myClass::display(){

    cout<<a<<endl;
    cout<<b<<endl;
}

int main(){

myClass class1(2,3);
myClass class2;

class2=class1;

class2.display();



return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you have a typo:

```
const myClass& myClass::operator=(const class & rightobj)
                                       //^^Should be myClass
```

Comment: ohh thanks i forgot that

Comment: @user3215228 you're welcome. BTW, `using namespace std` is considered bad practice. You may find a lot of posts here about why if interested.

Comment: it's bad practice in a header, it doesn't matter in a .cpp source file

Comment: why it is a bad practise??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5849457/981959

Comment: @user3215228 As it's compiler-only thing, it doesn't really matter unless you work on large team projects.

Comment: @Saraph It **always** matters.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Ummmmmm.... **nope**.