# C++operator overloading << and returning string getMonthName method

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading

I'm having trouble returning the string for the month. In the string `upDate::getMonthName`, the `getMonthName` is underlined and it says `Declaration is incompatible with <error-type> upDate getMonthName().`

I don't really understand why it doesn't work. For me, I think should be similar the `getMonth`, `getDay`, `getYear` methods, right?

Also, at the very bottom, I don't really understand the `ostream` operator. It says that the `ostream` is not identified? I know how to do other operating overloads like `operator++` and `operator=` but I'm kind of confused on how the `ostream` one works.

Sorry, I'm just confused about C++ overall :/

```
#include "upDate.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

upDate::upDate(){
    month = 5;
    day = 11;
    year = 1959;
}

upDate::upDate(int m, int d, int y) {
    if (((m == 1 || m == 3 || m == 5 || m == 7 || m == 8 || m == 12) && d > 31) ||
        ((m == 4 || m == 6 || m == 9 || m == 11) && d > 30 || (m > 12 || m < 1))) {
        month = 5;
        day = 11;
        year = 1959;
    }
    else if (m == 2 && d >= 29 && y % 4 != 0) {
        month = 5;
        day = 11;
        year = 1959;
    }
    else {
        month = m;
        day = d;
        year = y;
    }
}

void upDate::display() {

    switch (month) {
        case 1:
            cout << "January";
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "February";
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "March";
            break;
        case 4:
            cout << "April";
            break;
        case 5:
            cout << "May";
            break;
        case 6:
            cout << "June";
            break;
        case 7:
            cout << "July";
            break;
        case 8:
            cout << "August";
            break;
        case 9:
            cout << "September";
            break;
        case 10:
            cout << "October";
            break;
        case 11:
            cout << "November";
            break;
        case 12:
            cout << "December";
            break;
    }
    cout << " " << day << ", " << year;
}

void upDate::setDate(int m, int d, int y) {
    if (((m == 1 || m == 3 || m == 5 || m == 7 || m == 8 || m == 12) && d > 31) ||
        ((m == 4 || m == 6 || m == 9 || m == 11) && d > 30 || (m > 12 || m < 1))) {
        month = 5;
        day = 11;
        year = 1959;
    }
    else if (m == 2 && d >= 29 && y % 4 != 0) {
        month = 5;
        day = 11;
        year = 1959;
    }
    else {
        month = m;
        day = d;
        year = y;
    }
}
int upDate::getMonth() {
    return month;
}
int upDate::getDay() {
    return day;
}
int upDate::getYear() {
    return year;
}
string upDate::getMonthName(){
    string monthN;
    switch (month) {
        case 1:
            monthN = "January";
            break;
        case 2:
            monthN = "February";
            break;
        case 3:
            monthN = "March";
            break;
        case 4:
            monthN = "April";
            break;
        case 5:
            monthN = "May";
            break;
        case 6:
            monthN = "June";
            break;
        case 7:
            monthN = "July";
            break;
        case 8:
            monthN = "August";
            break;
        case 9:
            monthN = "September";
            break;
        case 10:
            monthN = "October";
            break;
        case 11:
            monthN = "November";
            break;
        case 12:
            monthN = "December";
            break;
    } return monthN;
}

// other methods

ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, upDate &L) {
    out << L.getDay() <<  ", " << L.getYear() << endl; //L.getMonthName() is supposed to         be here too
    return out;
}
```

and here is upDate.h

```
#ifndef MYDATE_H_
#define MYDATE_H_

class upDate {

    private:
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;


    public:
    upDate();
    upDate(int, int, int);

   void display();
   void setDate(int, int, int);

   int getMonth();
   int getDay();
   int getYear();
   int convertDateToJulian(int, int, int);
   int convertDateToGregorian(int, int&m, int&d, int&y);
   string getMonthName();

   upDate operator=(upDate);
   upDate operator++();
   upDate operator++(int);
   upDate operator+(int);
   friend upDate operator+(int, upDate);
   upDate operator--();
   upDate operator--(int);
   upDate operator-(int);
   int operator-(upDate);
   friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, upDate L);
```

};

#endif /* MYDATE_H_ */

Comment: Maybe there's an issue with the function prototype not matching the function. Also, please use white spaces and proper indention in your code...

Comment: Please show the contents of update.h

Comment: i guess the problem is in "upDate.h",chech the declaration in your class declaration .

Comment: Unrelated: Your code doesn't use `const`, which may cause you problems later on (e.g. when trying to output an `upDate` returned from a function).

Comment: please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the feeling this all boils down to simple inclusion problem. I don't see anywhere in your code the inclusion for `std::string` but regardless, you use it. So in your header add `#include <string>` after the include guard.

In a similar manner, also include `<ostream>` (and possibly `<iostream>`) for the `operator <<` to function properly. Modify `string getMonthName();` to be `std::string getMonthName();` since you do not want to use an entire namespace in your header file (see ["using namespace" in c++ headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849457/using-namespace-in-c-headers)).

Then two general comments: getters should be `const` and `operator +` can take in a const reference.

And finally the `operator <<` (which you identify as ostream operator) is simply streaming out the data into the given ostream and returns the same ostream in order to be chainable, such as:

```
std::cout << "Date:" << mydate << std::endl;
```

Here the compiler will use your `operator <<` to output what you want to see on the stream. Read this http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c++-iostreams.html for more about streaming in c++.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're not placing the *#include* directives in the header, but in the .cpp file. Put these lines inside the header file *upDate.h*:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
```