# C++ Struct and Class Compiler Errors

Tags: c++, class, struct, compiler-errors, abstract-data-type

The big two errors I'm getting are:

> uninitialized reference member in 'struct node' using 'new' without new-initializer.

and

> request for member 'a_student' in '((score*)this->score::sInfoHEAD', which is of non-class type 'node'.

My .cpp file is:

```
    #include "CS163Program1.h"
    using namespace std;

    score::score()
    {
      sInfoHEAD = '\0';
      profHEAD = '\0';
    }

   score::~score()
    {
      delete sInfoHEAD;
      delete profHEAD;
    }

   int score::insertEntry(studentInfo a_student)
   {
        if(!sInfoHEAD)
        {
             sInfoHEAD = new node;
             sInfoHEAD -> a_student = new studentInfo;

              sInfoHEAD.a_student -> firstName = new char[strlen(a_student.firstName)+1];
              strcpy(firstName, a_student.firstName);

              sInfoHEAD.a_student -> lastName = new char[strlen(a_student.lastName)+1];
              strcpy(lastName, a_student.lastName);

              sInfoHEAD.a_student -> program1_grade = a_student.program1_grade;
              sInfoHEAD.a_student -> program2_grade = a_student.program2_grade;
              sInfoHEAD.a_student -> program3_grade = a_student.program3_grade;
              sInfoHEAD.a_student -> program4_grade = a_student.program4_grade;
              sInfoHEAD.a_student -> program5_grade = a_student.program5_grade;
              sInfoHEAD.a_student -> midterm_grade = a_student.midterm_grade;
              sInfoHEAD.a_student -> final_grade = a_student.final_grade;
              sInfoHEAD.a_student -> labAttendance = a_student.labAttendance;
              sInfoHEAD -> next = NULL;
      }
```

}

My .h file is:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstring>
    #include <cctype>
    using namespace std;

    struct studentInfo
    {
      char * firstName;
      char * lastName;
      int program1_grade;
      int program2_grade;
      int program3_grade;
      int program4_grade;
      int program5_grade;
      int midterm_grade;
      int final_grade;
      int labAttendance;
      int total_grade;

    };

    class score
    {
      public:
              score();
              ~score();
              int insertEntry(const studentInfo  entry_name);
             int updateEntry(const studentInfo  entry_name);
              int displayAll();
              int displaySpecific(profDemo proficiency);
              int evaluate(profDemo proficiency);
              int buildTestStruct(const studentInfo & a_student);

      private:
              node * sInfoHEAD;
              node * profHEAD;


     };
```

any help would be vastly appreciated, I've been starting at it a good 3 hours and do not know how to fix it.

Comment: you should use std::string instead of char*

Comment: can you mark the line where you get the errors?

Comment: Can you show us the `node` declaration ? And by the way, `using namespace std;` in .h is not a good practice...

Comment: You are accessing the values of a pointer like a normal object. "."
sInfoHEAD -> a_student (is correct)
instead of 
"sInfoHEAD.a_student"

plus, int score::insertEntry(studentInfo a_student) should be
int score::insertEntry(studentInfo& a_student)

change it in the header as well.

Comment: Also, should Assign NULL to them "node" pointers in the constructor.

Answer (score 4):

Your `struct node` seems to have a reference member like:

```
struct node
{
    int& num;
};
```

This member should be initialize in the initializer-list in the constructor. (a reference cannot be null...)

```
struct node
{
    node( int& iNum ) : num( iNum ) {}

    int& num;
};
```

Also, you are accessing a pointer like if it was a value:

```
sInfoHEAD.a_student -> firstName
```

Should be :

```
sInfoHEAD->a_student -> firstName
//       ^^
```

And finally, when you are passing objects as arguments, try to pass them as references or `const` references when it is possible :

```
int insertEntry(const studentInfo  entry_name);
```

Should become :

```
int insertEntry(const studentInfo& entry_name);
//                               ^
```

---

And also, like I said in the comment: `using namespace std;` in header file is not a good practice. You can read this if you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5849668/1394283

Comment: You took words outta my mouth!

Comment: You have a dangerous error there. You initialize the reference to a temporary. -- edit: here: `node( int iNum ) : num( iNum ) {}` -- edit: solved, downvote removed :)

Comment: Ahah, I just read your comments ! It seems we made the same analysis :)

Comment: @phresnel You are right ! Sorry, just fixed this ! Thanks