# Using Directives in Implementation Files

Tags: c++, namespaces, using

In C++ Primer, there is one tips says:

> One place where `using` directives are useful is in the implementation
>   files for the namespace itself.

I guess this is just for using shorthand names? I am not sure how it is different from just surrounding the implementation with

```
namespace namespace_name
{
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That applies to modifications to your own namespaces. The purpose of `using` directives is to import symbols from a *different* namespace. For example, an infamous idiom:

```
namespace my_stuff
{
  template <typename Container>
  void my_fn( Container& xs )
  {
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    std::sort( begin(xs), end(xs) );
  }
}
```

Everything happens in *your* `my_namespace`, but it makes available the `std::begin()` and `std::end()` functions if needed. If a more local definition for `begin()` and `end()` exists that better matches the Container type, then it will be used instead. If you had simply wrapped everything in the std namespace, this useful ability would be lost.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not sure how it is different from just surrounding the implementation with `namespace namespace_name { }`

This is to put your own code within a namespace, as opposed to using some name from another namespace. Say you write a `draw` function inside the `Graphics` namespace -- to do this, you wrap `draw`'s code in `namespace Math { void draw() { /* some code */ } }` and to use it you'd do `Graphics::draw`. However, when you need to use a function, say, `gamma` in the `Math` namespace (which you didn't write), you've to call it `Math::gamma` for the compiler to know where to search for `gamma`. Alternatively, you may use shorthand, to drop the `Math::` part.

> I guess this is just for using shorthand names?

Yes, that's to allow identifiers from some namespace to be used without the qualifier. There are two ways to do it.

1. [Using directive](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-directives): Use all names in a namespace without qualification (e.g. `using namespace Math;`)
2. [Using declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration): Use only some specified names without qualification (e.g. `using Math::gamma`) -- this is usually better than the former.

However, both are encouraged to be used only in an implementation/source file and not in a header to avoid some sources which may have its own copy of `gamma` and don't want to use `Math::gamma`, but since you've it in the header, it'll lead a clash of the names. More details on ["using namespace" in c++ headers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5849457/183120).