# Erro c++ compiler: no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::operator<< .... Don`t know where is my error

Tags: c++

I am not permited to use friend relationships.This is my code:

```
   #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class CContacto{
     private:
         string nombre;
         string apellidos;
     public:
         CContacto(){};
         CContacto(string n,string a){
              nombre=n;
              apellidos=a;
          }
          string get_Nombre(void){return nombre;}
          string get_Apellido(void){return apellidos;};
    };

   class CMensaje{
      private:
          CContacto Remitente,Destinatario;
          string Asunto,Contenido;
     public:
          CMensaje(){};
          CMensaje(CContacto r,CContacto d,string a,string c){
                  Remitente=r;
                  Destinatario=d;
                  Asunto=a;
                  Contenido=c;
          }
```

Can not use friendship relation so this functions allows me to access to private members

```
         string get_contenido(void){return Contenido;}
         string get_Remit_Apellido(void){return Remitente.get_Apellido();}
         string get_Remit_Nombre(void){return Remitente.get_Nombre();}
         string get_Dest_Apellido(void){return Destinatario.get_Apellido();}
         string get_Dest_Nombre(void){return Destinatario.get_Nombre();}
         string getAsunto(void){return Asunto;}
         string getContenido(void){return Contenido;}
   };
```

This class allows me to print information from the other classes. The error here but i don´t what i have wrong. Need some help please

```
   class CAcciones{
     public: 
         void ImprimirDatosMensaje(CMensaje m){
          cout<<"Remitente: "<<m.get_Remit_Apellido()<<", "<<m.get_Remit_Nombre()<<endl;
          cout<<"Destinatario: "<<m.get_Dest_Apellido<<", "<<m.get_Dest_Nombre()<<endl;
          cout<<"Asunto: "<<m.getAsunto()<<endl;
          cout<<"Contenido: "<<m.getContenido()<<endl<<endl;
        }
      };
```

Comment: Use `#include <string>`

Comment: Have you made an effort to identify which of the `<<` operators is causing the problem? Comment out one at a time to identify if it is one, some or all of them.

Comment: What compiler are you using? What is the exact error message? Please do not put code in comments, edit the question by adding that code if you think it is relevant.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849457/using-namespace-in-c-headers