# Linker unresolved external symbol for inline function

Tags: c++

I'm developing a C++ solution with Visual Studio 2015.

I have a cpp source file and header file hpp with this declaration.

Header:

```
#ifndef MyLib__FREEFUNCTIONS__INCLUDE__
#define MyLib__FREEFUNCTIONS__INCLUDE__

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

// Check if 'str' is null, empty or consists only of white-space characters. 
inline bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace(string str);

// More functions
[ ... ]

#endif
```

And Source code:

```
#include "FreeFunctions.h"

inline bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace(string str)
{
    return (str.empty() || (str.find_first_not_of(' ') == string::npos));
}
```

I use this function in a class:

```
#include "ConvertToOwnFormat.h"
#include "FreeFunctions.h"

ConvertToOwnFormat::ConvertToOwnFormat()
{
}


ConvertToOwnFormat::~ConvertToOwnFormat()
{
}

vector<Entry> ConvertToOwnFormat::ReadCatalogue(string path)
{
    if (!IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path)
    {
        [ ... ]
    }
}
```

And I get the following error in `ConvertToOwnFormat::ReadCatalogue`:

> Error LNK2019 external symbol "bool __cdecl IsNullOrWhiteSpace(class
>   std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator >)"
>   (?IsNullOrWhiteSpace@@YA_NV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
>   unresolved referenced by the function "public: class std::vector > __cdecl
>   ConvertToOwnFormat::ReadCatalogue(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >)"
>   (?ReadCatalogue@ConvertToOwnFormat@@QEAA?AV?$vector@VEntry@@V?$allocator@VEntry@@@std@@@std@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@3@@Z)   MyProjectLib    D:\Fuentes\Repos\MyProject\MyProjectLibConsoleTest\ConsoleMyProjectLib\Lib.lib(ConvertToOwnFormat.obj)  1

Comment: I may be wrong, but inline I believe is usually for declaration of methods within the header, rather than the cpp file. Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes, I have tried and it links. Thanks.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but names that contain two consecutive underscores (`MyLib__FREEFUNCTIONS__INCLUDE__`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved to the implementation. Don't use them.

Comment: This isn't also the problem, but `using namespace` inside a header is discouraged (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849457/using-namespace-in-c-headers)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. I'm learning and they are much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to put declaration of methods within the header. `inline` tells to compiler that it should replace call of function with the core of function. So, it need it at compilation time for every unit of compilation which use it

```
#ifndef MyLib__FREEFUNCTIONS__INCLUDE__
#define MyLib__FREEFUNCTIONS__INCLUDE__

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

// Check if 'str' is null, empty or consists only of white-space characters. 
inline bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace(std::string str)
{
    return (str.empty() || (str.find_first_not_of(' ') == std::string::npos));
}

// Others functions, prototype, ...

#endif
```

or remove `inline` in both source and header files

---

It's totally out of topic but *never* put a `using namespace` inside a header: a header should offer something but should not impose something like namespace. See also ["using namespace" in c++ headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849457/using-namespace-in-c-headers)