# Issue with name of the class or namespace

Tags: c++, class, namespaces

Compiler say:students isn't the name of the class or of the namespace. And it say that "name" is undeclared .

students.cpp:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include "students.h"
using namespace std;
    void students::set_name(string student_name)
    {
        name = student_name;
    }
```

students.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include "students.cpp"
using namespace std;
class students
{   public:
            void set_name(string student_name); 
    private:
            string name;
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include "students.h"
#include "students.cpp"
using namespace std;  
    int main()
    {
        students *student = new students;
        std::string name;
        std::cout << "Name: ";
        getline(std::cin, name);
        student->set_name(name);
        delete student;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

update: after i've removed " #include "students.cpp" " i got:

```
 1>students.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall students::set_name(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?set_name@students@@QAEXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) уже определен в main.obj
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not include the .cpp file in the students.h file, just omit

```
#include "students.cpp"
```

Additional tip: Omit

```
using namespace std;
```

in the header file to avoid namespace clashes, see this [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849457/using-namespace-in-c-headers)

Answer (score 0):

LNK2005 means that symbol was already defined, you have added:

```
#include "students.cpp"
```

in two places in your source files so you have multiple definitions for your `students::set_name(string student_name)`. You should never include .cpp files in source files. Add `students.cpp` in your project, then remove all occurences of `#include "students.cpp"` in your sources.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove  `#include "students.cpp"` from both main.cpp and students.h.