# Can't include <QtCharts/QLineSeries>

Tags: c++, qt, qtcharts

It seems I can't find a way to include `<QtCharts/QLineSeries>` in my header so Qt knows about the QLineSeries class.

- I added `Qt += charts` to my .pro file.
- I added `#include <QtCharts/QLineSeries>` to `MainWindow.h`
- Then I delete .pro.user file and any builds I've done. And then reopen the .pro file to reconfigure the project in the cleanest way.
- Finally I set the build mode to `Release`, run QMake by right-clicking the project and selecting it and Run it.

I get the message:

```
 ...\PlottingCharts\mainwindow.h:14: error: 'QLineSeries' does not name a type
     QLineSeries *series;
     ^
```

So clearly Qt doesn't know anything about QLineSeries.

For reference, the `linechart` and `openglseries` examples work correctly.

Any one knows what I'm missing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As I wrote the question I found the answer.

I was missing `using namespace QtCharts;` in the header file.
Got the reference from: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-index.html

Comment: Indeed the error you had was a compiler error, complaining that a type was undefined, not that the include was not found ! 
For people falling on this issue, if they got linker error about symbols not found, then it's because they have forgotten to add Qt += charts in the .pro file (or forgotten to reapply qmake)

Comment: You should never put a `using namespace` declaration in a header file. This is bad coding practice. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5849668/3964397 for more details.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to avoid specifying the namespace, you can also declare your variable as:

```
QtCharts::QLineSeries *series;
```

With this solution you **always** have to prepend `QtCharts::`, but you also know your scope and the origin of your calls.