# Unexpected #ifndef, No Matching Function Call (Linked List C++)

Tags: c++, linked-list, function-calls, ifndef

Hi i am currently working on a linked list project but am receiving a few errors while doing so that I can't seem to solve. The first error i am getting is an *undetermined #ifndef*. What im confused about is that I didnt #include a source file in the header.

My second error I am getting is in my main.cpp, where I am getting an error saying " *no matching function call to 'List::AddNode(double, double, double,etc)*".

I have posted all three of my files in hopes of someone helping me figure out these errors I am receiving, Thank You.

EDIT: Thank you for those who helped me, that has solved my problem but now I am receiving new errors saying
*"undefined reference to List::List()',*

*undefined reference to List::AddNode(double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double)',*

*undefined reference to `List::PrintList()'".*

Main

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "List.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    List Moe;

    Moe.AddNode(23.00, 7.00, 12.75, 7.65, 1.00,45.00, 0.18, 50.00);
    Moe.PrintList();
}
```

Header File

```
#ifndef LIST_H_INCLUDED
#define LIST_H_INCLUDED
#endif LIST_H_INCLUDED

using namespace std;
class List
{
private:

    struct node{
        double adults, children,costA,costC,dessert,room,tt,deposit;
        node* next, *link;

    };
    typedef struct node* nodePtr;

    nodePtr head;
    nodePtr curr;
    nodePtr temp;

public:
    List();
    void AddNode(double addAdults,double addChildren, double addCostA, double addCostC,double addDessert, double addRoom, double addTT, double addDeposit);
    void PrintList();
};
```

CPP File

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "List.h"

using namespace std;

List::List()
{
    head = NULL;
    curr = NULL;
    temp = NULL;
}
void List::AddNode(double addAdults,double addChildren, double addCostA, double addCostC,double addDessert, double addRoom, double addTT, double addDeposit)
{
    nodePtr n = new node;
    n->next = NULL;

    n->adults = addAdults;
    //cout >> "Number of Adults: " >> addAdults;
    n->children = addChildren;
    n->costA = addCostA;
    n->costC = addCostC;
    n->dessert = addDessert;
    n->room = addRoom;
    n->tt = addTT;
    n->deposit = addDeposit;

    if(head != NULL)
    {
        curr = head;
        while(curr -> next != NULL)
        {
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        curr->next = n;
    }
    else
    {
        head = n;
    }
}
void List::PrintList()
{
    curr = head;
    while(curr != NULL)
    {
        cout << "Total cost for adult meals:        $" << (curr -> adults) * (curr -> costA) << endl;
            cout << "Total cost for child meals:        $" << ((curr -> children) *(curr -> costA)) * 0.60 << endl;
            cout << "Total cost for dessert:            $" << ((curr -> adults) + (curr -> children)) * (curr -> dessert) << endl;
            cout << "Total food cost:                   $" <<(curr -> adults) * (curr -> costA) +
                                                           (curr -> children) *(curr -> costA) * 0.60 +
                                                           ((curr -> adults) + (curr -> children)) * (curr -> dessert)<< endl;
            cout << "Plus tips and tax:                 $" <<curr -> tt * ((curr -> adults) * (curr -> costA) +
                                                           (curr -> children) *(curr -> costA) * 0.60 +
                                                           ((curr -> adults) + (curr -> children)) * (curr -> dessert)) <<
                                                            " (Does NOT Include Room Fee)" << endl;
            cout << "Plus room fee:                     $" << (curr -> room) << endl;
            cout << "Less Deposit:                      $";
            cin >>curr -> deposit;
            cout << "" << endl;
            cout << "Balance Due:                      $" << /*FOOD COST*/((curr -> adults) * (curr -> costA) +
                                                           (curr -> children) *(curr -> costA) * 0.60 +
                                                           ((curr -> adults) + (curr -> children)) * (curr -> dessert)) +
                                                           /*TIPS & TAX*/ (curr -> tt * ((curr -> adults) * (curr -> costA) +
                                                           (curr -> children) *(curr -> costA) * 0.60 +
                                                           ((curr -> adults) + (curr -> children)) * (curr -> dessert))) +
                                                           /*ROOM FEE */ ((curr -> room)) - /*DEPOSIT*/ (curr -> deposit) << endl;
            cout << "" << endl;

            curr = curr->next;

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to pay attention to how header guards are used. Also, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849457/using-namespace-in-c-headers) regarding `using namespace` in a header.

Comment: Please don't edit the error message, you have removed important information.

Comment: I didnt remove any important information from the error message, after the double it is just double, double, double, double, double.

Comment: How are you compiling your program?  It appears you are not compiling and linking your list.cpp/list.obj files.  For future reference, if you can't solve an error on your own, you aren't the one to determine what is and is not important in an error message. A little too much is better than not enouh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstood the way [header guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) are used: you need a conditional compile statement to guard the entire content of the header, not just the `#define`. Move `#endif` to the end of the file, and remove or comment out `LIST_H_INCLUDED` at the end:

```
#ifndef LIST_H_INCLUDED
#define LIST_H_INCLUDED

using namespace std;
class List
{
private:

    struct node{
        double adults, children,costA,costC,dessert,room,tt,deposit;
        node* next, *link;

    };
    typedef struct node* nodePtr;

    nodePtr head;
    nodePtr curr;
    nodePtr temp;

public:
    List();
    void AddNode(double addAdults,double addChildren, double addCostA, double addCostC,double addDessert, double addRoom, double addTT, double addDeposit);
    void PrintList();
};

#endif /* LIST_H_INCLUDED */
```

Answer (score 0):

The *main* error you have is with your header guards. Currently, you do this:

```
#ifndef LIST_H_INCLUDED
#define LIST_H_INCLUDED
#endif LIST_H_INCLUDED
```

*before* you begin your code, which really has no effect, since the header guards don't actually *guard* anything. Thus when you include "List.h" twice, the compiler complains. The proper way to do it would be

```
#ifndef LIST_H_INCLUDED
#define LIST_H_INCLUDED

//... List code ...

#endif //Endif goes at the end of file
```

Thus, if the file "List.h" is already included, you won't accidently include it again. Also, if you want to make it easier for yourself and are compiling on a compiler that supports the operation, you can use the following:

```
#pragma once

//... List code ...
```

The `#pragma once` does the same thing as the include guards, although it is nonstandard but largely supported by most if not all new compilers.

Comment: Thank you! This solved both of my problems, i am fairly new to C++ so please forgive me, but now in my main file has a new errors stating undefined reference to `List::List()', undefined reference to `List::AddNode(double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double)', and undefined reference to `List::PrintList()'.