# Separating interface from implementation isn't working c++

Tags: c++, object

Hey i was trying to use Separating interface from implementation but got error.
Not understanding what's wrong.
Here's my program 
[here's the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOACz.jpg)

```
#include<iostream>
#include"name.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x,y;
    cin>>x>>y;
    name n1(x,y);
    n1.getdata(x,y);
    n1.showdata();
}
```

now here's the created header file

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class name{
private:
    int a,b;
public:
    name(int x, int y);
    void getdata(int x, int y);
    int showdata();
};
```

& here's the next part of class

```
#include"name.h"
using namespace std;
name::name(int x, int y)
{
    a=0;
    b=0;
}
void name::getdata(int x,int y)
{
    a=x;
    b=y;
}
void name::showdata()
{
    cout<<a+b;
}
```

Comment: which error do you get?

Comment: @yeasir arafat shahed  The parameters in the constructor name::name(int x, int y)
{
    a=0;
    b=0;
} are not used. So the declaration of the constructor does not make sense.

Comment: @yeasir arafat shahed  It is better to name the method getdata as setdata or even set_data

Comment: That `name` constructor looks bad for two reasons: 1) it should use the initialization list, not the constructor body (and yes, it matters for performance in many cases). 2) it doesn't actually use the arguments passed in.

Comment: `name::getdata` looks mis-named. Shouldn't it be named `name::setdata` since that's what it does; it *sets* the member variables.

Comment: Look at `showdata`’s prototype in the header. Then look at `showdata`’s implementation. Keep looking until you spot the difference.

Comment: my 2c: `name.h` misses header guard; `using namespace` in header is usually [bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849457/using-namespace-in-c-headers)

Comment: `using namespace std;` - please don't. You are completely obliterating the whole point of having namespases in the first place. *Especially don't do that in a header* where you will impose your bad choice on all users. Using `using namespace` in a header is a *huge* code smell.

Comment: @AMA s Folder\Study\CSE107\Practice\Practice 16.10\2.o:2.cpp|| undefined reference to `name::name(int, int)'|
s Folder\Study\CSE107\Practice\Practice 16.10\2.o:2.cpp|| undefined reference to `name::getdata(int, int)'|
s Folder\Study\CSE107\Practice\Practice 16.10\2.o:2.cpp|| undefined reference to `name::showdata()'|
||=== Build failed: 3 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 4 second(s)) ===|

Comment: Please put the error-info inside the question, so that everyone can see it.

Comment: May I recommend reading [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 2):

There are many problems with your code. It looks like the best advice in this situation would be to read a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

When this is out of the way, here's the short-list of problems in the severity-descending order:

- `name::showdata()` declaration signature does not match difinitioin: `int showdata()` vs. `void showdata()`
- header misses an [include guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)
- `using namespace` in a header is [a code smell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849457/using-namespace-in-c-headers) 99 times out of 100
- header does not need to include `<iostream>`, it would suffice to include it in implementation file, where it's actually used.

By looking at undefined references you are getting, I would also guess that `name.cpp` is not build.

I fixed some of the mentioned points to just make it build:
 <kbd>[**Live Demo**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/x1WWZJFN9QVF4BD2)</kbd>

Comment: I have tried following your instruction edited some mistakes  [check this out](https://imgur.com/Oi7oh63) but the error is still there  [error](https://imgur.com/er4BcrA)

Comment: @yeasirarafatshahed I guess that `name.cpp` is not added to the build. Probably it's a problem in your project configuration and not in the code. Please check your configuration and make sure that `name.cpp` is added.