# Template Pointer as member

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, forward-declaration

I got two classes "DTreeEmbedder" and "modifier".
Embedder is a template class and I want to manipulate member variables of "DTreeEmbedder".

class DTreeEmbedder:

```
class modifier; //forward declaration of modifier

using namespace ogdf;
using namespace ogdf::energybased::dtree;

template<int Dim>
class DTreeEmbedder
{
  public:
  //! constructor with a given graph, allocates memory and does 
  initialization
  explicit DTreeEmbedder(GLFWwindow * w, const Graph& graph);

  //! destructor
  virtual ~DTreeEmbedder();

  modifier* m_modifier;
```

In constructor

```
  template<int Dim>
  DTreeEmbedder<Dim>::DTreeEmbedder(GLFWwindow * w, const Graph& graph) : 
             m_graph(graph)
  {
        m_modifier = new modifier();
  }
```

Both objects need access to each other, therefore the forward declaration.

```
#pragma once

#include "DTreeEmbedder.h"

class modifier
{
  public:
    modifier(DTreeEmbedder<int>* e);
    ~modifier();

    DTreeEmbedder<int>* m_embedder;

    void pca_project(int pc1,int pc2);
 };
```

pca_project is a function that should change values / call functions in m_embedder

In constructor of modifier:

```
modifier::modifier(DTreeEmbedder<int>* e)
{
   m_embedder = e;
}
```

pca function:

```
void modifier::pca_project(int pc1, int pc2)
{
   m_embedder->stop();
}
```

My approach therefore is:

1. Create DTreeEmbedder
2. DTreeEmbedder creates modifier with pointer of itself
3. modifier got the pointer to DTreeEmbedder and can now change values of that object

My errors are:

```
"int": Invalid type for the non-type template parameter "Dim"
This pointer can not be converted from "DTreeEmbedder" to "DTreeEmbedder <Dim> &"
```

Thx in advance

Comment: What do you mean by `template<int Dim>`?

Comment: @CinCout it's a non-type template parameter

Comment: then it should not be `DTreeEmbedder<int>` but rather something like `DTreeEmbedder<42>` in the modifier class

Comment: [**Do not** use `using namespace` in headers!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5849457/1968)

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph DTreeEmbedder is a header only file and i need the namespace to gain access to another class

Comment: @bobah best case would be, if the pointer stays variable

Comment: @dondroelf Please read the text I linked to. You can *use* a namespace, you simply mustn’t import it via `using namespace` on the file level.

Comment: "template class". I suspect this is part of your problem. The usual English syntax parses that as a "a class, which is usable as a template". The problem is, there's no such thing in C++. What C++ has are **class templates**. They are templates. Because they're templates, they can be **instantiated**. And the instantiation of a class template is a class. (And by the same logic, the instantiation of a function template is a function).

Answer (score 1):

> Change `template<int Dim>` to `template<class Dim>`

**OR**

Look at the error closely, it says:-

`"int": Invalid type for the non-type template parameter "Dim"`

**Here you have assigned a class inside a parameter that you have so declared as `template<int Dim>.`**

What **"non-type"** here stands for is that you are assigning a class inside a template whose parameter is an `int` (**NOT** `class`).

> **Example:**
>
> ```
> template<int Dim>
> int Sum(int with)
> {
>     return Dim + with;
> }
> ```
>
> ---
>
> **Explanation:**
>
> Here, a "function template" is declared with a template parameter `Dim` of type `int`. This is the **variable** that will hold the *integer*(Not a class, a.k.a, what you are trying to do there...) that will be assigned to it when used. Like so:-
>
> `auto S = Sum<2>(2);`
>
> Here you have assigned an integer **"`2`"** in the parameters, the template takes the value of `Dim` (In this case, **2**) and adds it with `with`, (**2** in this case) parameter inside the function and returns the result of the expression. (**2 + 2 = 4**)
>
> ---
>
> Where your problem lies is in this constructor,
>
> `modifier(DTreeEmbedder<int>* e)`
>
> Here, there is one problem, given that you have declared `Dim` there as an integer, now adding a class `int` inside the parameter is wrong...
>
> *So it should be:-*
>
> `modifier(DTreeEmbedder<111>* e) // Or any other number, since Dim is an integer`
>
> Think of this template parameter as a real integer variable, so you are doing something like:-
>
> `int Dim = int; /*Which is a type (class)*/`
>
> in
>
> `DTreeEmbedder<int> /*Assigning a class to an integer (Dim in this case)*/`
>
> **The other error is an assignment error, check if both the variables are same, even the integer values assigned inside the template have to match since Dim is an integer...**
>
> Like, `DTreeEmbedder<90>` is not equal to `DTreeEmbedder<91>` or something like that...

Kind regards,

Ruks.