# How can I define my class in a different source file to my main function?

Tags: c++

Trivial as it ought to be, I just cannot figure out how to separate my source code into different files.

My code compiles and executes just fine when it is written as a single source file:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Greeter{ 
    public:
        void greet();
};

void Greeter::greet(){
    cout << "Hello World!";
}

int main(){
    Greeter greeter;
    greeter.greet();
    return 0;
}
```

But try as I might, separating the code into separate source files:

***Greeter.h***

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Greeter{ 
    public:
        Greeter();
        void greet();
};
```

***Greeter.cxx***

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Greeter.h"
using namespace std;

void Greeter::greet(){
    cout << "Hello World!";
}
```

***main.cxx***

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Greeter.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    Greeter greeter;
    greeter.greet();
    return 0;
}
```

always results in a compilation error:

```
main.cxx:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `Greeter::Greeter()'
```

Comment: how are you compiling?

Comment: Simply add the braces in `Greeter.h`, e.g. `Greeter() {};` (avoid `using namespace std;` in any header, instead remove it and just use `std::cout`) Also include header-guards in `Greeter.h` (e.g. `#ifndef _my_class_greeter_h_ #define _my_class_greeter_h_ ... #endif`)

Comment: Look at your code carefully, before and after.  You added a `Greeter()` user-defined default constructor when you didn't have one before.

Comment: See [Default constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) paying very careful attention to the text within the `(...)` contained in the first sentence of the description, particularly the `"empty parameter list"` part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is unclear whether the comments solved your problem. In separating your source into a header and multiple sources, your primary problem evidenced by the error is that you include an incomplete constructor for `class Greeter` in `Greeter.h`. Specifically, you fail to include *"an empty parameter list"* to complete the constructor, e.g.

```
    Greeter() {};   /* default construct */
```

See [cppreference - Default constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor)

The next issue you should avoid is including `using namespace std;` in the header file. See [“using namespace” in c++ headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849457/using-namespace-in-c-headers). Instead, simply make your call to `cout`, `std::cout` and eliminate the need to include the namespace altogether.

Next, while `iostream` has proper header guards, you only need to include it in `Greeter.cpp` (that is the only source making use of an `iostream` function). You should also include header guards in your `Greeter.h` to prevent multiple inclusions during compilation. Simply create a `#define` and check whether or not that is already defined within the header, e.g.

**greeter.h**

```
#ifndef my_class_greeter_h
#define my_class_greeter_h  1

class Greeter { 

    public:
        Greeter() {};   /* default construct */
        void greet();
};

#endif
```

Now every file that includes `greeter.h` will avoid including it again if `my_class_greeter_h` is already defined.

**greeter.cpp**

Your source file with your class function definition is the only source that relies on an `iostream` call, and is the only file that requires `#include <iostream>`, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>

#include "greeter.h"

void Greeter::greet(){
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

**main.cpp**

You `main.cpp` source file need only include your header containing the class definition, e.g.

```
#include "greeter.h"

int main (void) {

    Greeter greeter;    /* instantiate greeter */
    greeter.greet();    /* call greet() */

    return 0;
}
```

**Both Sources Must Be Compiled**

Compiling the separate source files requires that both `main.cpp` and `greeter.cpp` be compiled (either compiling `greeter.cpp` to object or by simply including both `.cpp` files in your compile string).

*Compiling With `gcc/clang`*

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++11 -Ofast -o main main.cpp greeter.cpp
```

*Compiling With VS (`cl.exe`)*

```
> cl /nologo /W3 /Ox /EHsc /Femain /TP main.cpp greeter.cpp
```

(do not accept code until it compiles without warning)

**Example Use/Output**

In either case, the output is as expected:

```
$ ./main
Hello World!
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: I hesitated to even ask this question as I thought it likely far too trivial and not worth bothering the community. Thankfully, you're answer has not only solved my issue, but shown that even in such a short and basic piece of code, there is a lot of room for "good practice" improvements. Hopefully your answer help others as it did me. Thank you.

Comment: The very first header to include in `greeter.cpp` should be the corresponding `greeter.h`. This ensures that `greeter.h` is self-contained. The order of additional includes in `greeter.cpp` is less important as long as they are after `greeter.h`. My personal preference is to include project headers next (those in `""`) and system headers last (those in `<>`).

Comment: Wise point. I generally rely on the standard headers are guarded properly (perhaps wrongly) so they would only be included once regardless of order, but I do like your approach of including your source header as the first ensuring that compilation using is self contained. I can see instances where there would be additional includes (like `iostream here` necessary only for the internal workings of the source file. Thanks.