# Expected ‘)’ before ‘name’

Tags: c++

I'm writing the header file for a class that communicates with an Arduino, and I keep getting the above error message. I looked at other similar questions, and a reoccuring problem is that the data type in question is not well-defined. Is there any reason why std::string isn't defined, or is there another issue? Thanks in advance!

Edit: The following code is for the Linux Machine I'm using to communicate with the Arduino, and therefore isn't the Arduino code.  Also the full error message is:
error: expected ‘)’ before ‘name’
   ArduinoCom(std::string name, speed_t baud);

```
#ifndef ArduinoCom
#define ArduinoCom

#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <termios.h>
#include "SerialCom.h"

class ArduinoCom {
    public:
        ArduinoCom(std::string name, speed_t baud);
        ~ArduinoCom();
        std::string get_value(std::string value_type); 
        double get_double_value(std::string value_type);
    private:
        SerialCom *ard_serial;
};
#endif
```

And the corresponding .cpp file:

```
#include "ArduinoCom.h"
#include "SerialCom.h"

using namespace std;

ArduinoCom::ArduinoCom(std::string name, speed_t baud){
    ard_serial = new SerialCom(name, baud);
}

ArduinoCom::~ArduinoCom(){
    delete ard_serial;
}

std::string ArduinoCom::get_value(std::string value_type){
    ard_serial->write(value_type);
    std::string buf;
    ard_serial->read(buf);
    return buf;
}

double ArduinoCom::get_double_value(std::string value_type){
    std::value_str = ArduinoCom::get_value(value_type);
    return stod(value_str);
}
```

Comment: We don't have enough code to reproduce the error. The code you provided looks fine. Could you provide the full error message?

Comment: Apart from that, you'll want to have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849457/using-namespace-in-c-headers

Comment: `using namespace std;` in a header file is a very bad idea, get rid of it

Comment: Well, for starters, `ArduinoCom(std::string name, speed_t baud);` in the header conflicts with `ArduinoCom::ArduinoCom(int name, speed_t baud)` in the cpp.

Comment: can you include your `SerialCon.h` as well?

Answer (score 0):

Arduino IDE does not come with the C++ STL by default, instead Arduino has its own set of libraries. For Arduino development you would use the provided `String` object instead of `std::string`.

Also, you should check out

- https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/
- https://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'll edit the above question, but the above code is for the Linux machine communicating with the Arduino, and isn't for the Arduino itself.  Thank you for responding though