# How to initialize SparseMatrix of Eigen in a class

Tags: c++, eigen

I am trying initializing sparseMatrix of Eigen, but it does not work when the initialization is in a class description. In the case of initialization in a function, not in a class, it works. 
I am writting codes by C++ and using Visual Studio 2017.
I added 
    public:
    EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW , but the problem remains.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <Eigen/SparseCore>
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
#include "pch.h"

using namespace Eigen;
namespace A {
    class A 
    {
        std::size_t max_doc_id = 4;
        std::size_t max_term_id = 4;
        SparseMatrix<float, Eigen::RowMajor, int64_t> smat(max_term_id, max_doc_id); 
    public:
        EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW
    };
```

I want to decide the size of smat matrix (col=4, row=4) , but the error message is like this (actually it is written in Japanese so it may not correct)
    "the member A::A::max_term_id is not the name of the type."
I appreciate if you can help me.

Comment: As a side note, no need for `EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW` in the case of `SparseMatrix`.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler thinks that you are declaring a member function not a member variable (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) for more info on initialization). The following compiles. I am using `Index` instead of `size_t` to get rid of some warnings (narrowing conversion). You can play around with the code here: https://godbolt.org/z/yV1NUL

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <Eigen/SparseCore>
#include <Eigen/Sparse>

using namespace Eigen;
namespace A {
    class A 
    {
        Index max_doc_id = 4;
        Index max_term_id = 4;
        SparseMatrix<float, Eigen::RowMajor, int64_t> smat{max_term_id, max_doc_id}; 
    public:
        EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW
    };

}
```

Note: you should not use `using namespace` in header files, see ["using namespace" in c++ headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849457/using-namespace-in-c-headers)

**Edit:** please also consider what user @ggael says in the comments, most likely you do not need `EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW` because the `SparseMatrix` is not [fixed-size vectorizable](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicFixedSizeVectorizable.html)