# Trouble with header files; "redefinition of class"

Tags: c++, replit

I'm working on a problem from class. It's about creating an "addressType" class, and using it to interact with a main function that's already written out.
The program doesn't work, and the main error I get is "addressType.cpp:6:7: error: redefinition of 'addressType' class addressType {". Why does it think I'm redeclaring the class? I guess I'm just not familiar enough with C++ syntax. I'm really inexperienced with C++, I was a Java guy.

Here's a sample of my .h file code...

```
#ifndef ADDRESSTYPE_H_INCLUDED
#define ADDRESSTYPE_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class addressType {

private:
  string address;
  string city;
  string state;
  int zipcode;

public:
  addressType();

  addressType(string inputAddress, string inputCity, string inputState, int inputZipcode);

  void setAddress(string inputAddress);

  void setCity (string inputCity);

//more functions i didn't paste
}; #endif
```

and so on. Here's a sample of the .cpp:

```
#include "addressType.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class addressType {

private:
  string address;
  string city;
  string state;
  int zipcode;

public
  addressType() {
    address = "aa";
    city = "aa";
    state = "XX";
    zipcode = 10000;
  }

  addressType(string inputAddress, string inputCity, string inputState, int inputZipcode) {
    address = inputAddress;
    city = inputCity;
    setState(inputState);
    setZipcode(inputZipcode);
  }

  void setAddress(string inputAddress) {
    address = inputAddress;
  }
  //more functions I didn't paste
};
```

The main message I get is:
    addressType.cpp:6:7: error: redefinition of 'addressType'
class addressType.

Comment: I see two classes called addressType

Comment: `class addressType {...` in `my.h` and `class addressType {...` in the `.cpp` file. That's a redefinition if I've ever seen one. Leave the one in the header and simply create an instance of the class in the `.cpp` file.

Comment: As far as I know, `#endif` not at the start of a line (only after blanks) won't works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two things:

- get rid of the definition of `addressType` in the .cpp file completely
- prefix the methods that make up the class with `addressType::`, e.g. `void addressType::setAddress(string inputAddress) {...`

In that way, you define the class only once (which is a requirement, in any single translation unit), and you tell the compiler to which class the method bodies belong.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does it think I'm redeclaring the class?

Because you are.

More specifically though, redeclaration is not a problem. Redefinition is the problem. The first definition is in the `addressType.h` file. You include this file into "the .cpp" and then redefine `addressType`. This violates the one definition rule.

The solution is to not define the class more than once.

Answer (score 0):

@Paul Sanders answered it for you, but just to show you what he is saying:

.h

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

class AddressType {

private:
  std::string address;
  std::string city;
  std::string state;
  int zipcode;

public:
  AddressType();
  AddressType(std::string inputAddress, std::string inputCity, std::string inputState, int inputZipcode);
};
```

.cpp

```
#include "add.h"

using namespace std;

AddressType::AddressType()
{
  address = "aa";
  city = "aa";
  state = "XX";
  zipcode = 10000;
}

AddressType::AddressType(string inputAddress, string inputCity, string inputState, int inputZipcode)
  : address(inputAddress)
  , city(inputCity)
  , state(inputState)
  , zipcode(inputZipcode)
{
  // no-op
}
```

Also unrelated to your question, a suggestion, avoid `using namespace` in your headers: ["using namespace" in c++ headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849457/using-namespace-in-c-headers)