# C++ Multiple inheritance problem on accessing second derived class variables

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a base class A and in this class, there is a vector of the derived class B, and I add class C objects to this list (C is a derived class of B).
But now I am not able to access any variable either from B or C.

My class structure goes like this:

[image]

**Skill.h**

```
class Skill
{

public:

    Skill()
    {

    }

    vector <AttackSkill*> attacks;
    vector <UtilitySkill*> utilities;
    vector <MoveSkill*> movement;

};
```

**AttackSkill.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Skill.h"

class AttackSkill :
    public Skill
{

public:

    AttackSkill()
    {

    }

    string skillName;       
    int dmgMod;
    int baseAcc;

};
```

**One of the skills**

```
#pragma once
#include "AttackSkill.h"

class Axeblade :
    public AttackSkill
{
public:
    Axeblade()
    {
        skillName = "Axeblade";     
        dmgMod = 0;
        baseAcc = 72;
    }

};
```

**This is how to add new skill**

```
attacks.push_back(new Axeblade);
```

I just want to be able to access variables.

**Example:**

"skillPtr" is a pointer to Skill object

```
for (int i = 0; i < skillPtr->attacks.size(); i++) //No problem here
{
    cout << "Skill " << i << ") " << skillPtr->attacks[i]->skillName << endl;
}
```

> Error C2039 'skillName': is not a member of 'Skill'

Comment: Do you really want to have/inherit vector members in sub classes?

Comment: What do you mean by "But now I am not able to access any variable either from B or C.".?Do you get some kind of error message?

Comment: @Melebius Well there are multiple skills and I have a character that I want to be able to add and remove skills from.

Comment: This is not related to what I was speaking about. By inheriting `Skill`, you are getting those three vectors in each subclass. And please show us a [mcve]. Too many things remain unclear as you presented just bits of your code. In a comment you speak about `heroes[0]` but how is it defined?! http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Comment: @Melebius Ah okay I just understood you, I added an example. Also i was confused i wanted to say attacks[0], not heroes it is not important to our topic.

Comment: Following your code sample, I tried to do a complete reproducer: https://godbolt.org/z/HiwDad . What is your question on this example? 
(NB: I use unique_ptr as a good practice to avoid memory leaks)

Comment: I just tried @PascalH.'s solution. It works perfectly fine. If you even write ` std::cout << h.skillPtr->attacks[0]->skillName << std::endl;;` in his code (don't forget to include <iostream>) then it prints Axeblade.

Comment: With the error 'Error C2039 'skillName': is not a member of 'Skill'' I assume that in your code (not here in your sample) `attacks` field should be a `vector <Skill*>` not a `vector <AttackSkill*>`. Is it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am doing some guesswork here since the question is not fully specific but it might help…

Your `class Skill` contains three vectors (aggregation) and it’s inherited by subclasses defining skill types (inheritance). You should break these two principles apart. There should be one class containing the vectors for a character, let me call it `SkillSet`. (By the way, you should [never issue `using namespace` in a header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849457/using-namespace-in-c-headers).)

```
class SkillSet
{
public:
    std::vector <AttackSkill *> attacks;
    std::vector <UtilitySkill *> utilities;
    std::vector <MoveSkill *> movement;
};
```

Then there will be *another* base class for all skills which would contain the properties which all skills have:

```
class Skill
{
public:
    std::string skillName;       
};
```

Then you can inherit this new `Skill` class:

```
class AttackSkill :
    public Skill
{

public:
    int dmgMod;
    int baseAcc;
};

class Axeblade :
    public AttackSkill
{
public:
    Axeblade()
    {
        skillName = "Axeblade";     
        dmgMod = 0;
        baseAcc = 72;
    }
};
```

After creating and filling a `SkillSet` object:

```
SkillSet hero0;
hero0.attacks.push_back(new Axeblade);
```

You can simply access its public members:

```
std::cout << hero0.attacks[0]->skillName;
```

See the [example of my code](https://ideone.com/FiPLwZ).

A few more notes to consider:

- You don’t need vectors of pointers, you can put the objects directly to the vector. A vector is not a plain array.
- Instead of making the properties public, consider using [setters and getters](https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_encapsulation.asp).
- Your code contains empty constructors. There is no need to write a constructor that is empty.
- On the other hand, if your code contains objects created using `new`, you should `delete` them, e.g. in a destructor.