# namespace extern variable already defined

Tags: c++

I cannot compile my C++ program and I don't understand why.
Here's a simple representation of what is throwing errors:

**hello/hello.cpp**

```
#include "hello.h"

namespace MyHelloNS {
        MyHelloClass::MyHelloClass() {
            MyHelloVAR1 = "hi";
            MyHelloVAR2 = "dog";
        }
}
```

**hello/hello.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

using namespace std;

namespace MyHelloNS {
    extern string MyHelloVAR1;
    extern string MyHelloVAR2;

    class MyHelloClass;
}

class MyHelloNS::MyHelloClass {
public:
    MyHelloClass();
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "hello/hello.h"

int main() {
    MyHelloNS::MyHelloClass hi1;
}
```

I get two kinds of errors:
`unresolved external symbol in hello.obj`

What's wrong?

Comment: Post the full errors... explaining **what** is "unresolved" or "already defined".

Comment: Did you already try a re-build instead of a simple compile? (I've seen cases before where "unresolved" cases could be solved like this)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to include a full and complete copy-paste of the error messages you get.

Comment: By the way, nowhere do you actually *define* the variables `MyHelloNS::MyHelloVAR1` and `MyHelloNS::MyHelloVAR2`. In the header file you only *declare* them.

Comment: Never "using namespace ..." in .h files: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5849668/3378179

Comment: The screen shot of the errors doesn't match the description you made of the errors. There's no 'already defined' errors in the screen shot.

Comment: Visual Studio have a tab where you can get the errors *as text*. Please always copy-paste errors as text rather than images. Images can't be searched, it's not possibly to copy-paste parts of the "text" in them, and they don't work with screen-readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to main.cpp (or hello.cpp)

```
namespace MyHelloNS {
    string MyHelloVAR1;
    string MyHelloVAR2;
}
```

This question has nothing to do with namespaces, you just aren't following the correct procedure to define a global variable.

Comment: I don't get how I am not defining the variable in the header file?

Comment: `extern` means that you are *declaring* the variable in the header file (which is correct). You can declare a variable as many times as you like, but you must *define* it only once. So declare in the header file and define in one cpp file.

Comment: Basically you need to understand the difference between declaration and definition. A declaration just says that a variable (or function or whatever) is defined somewhere else. The linkers job is to resolve all declarations to their definitions. If the linker finds zero definitions or multiple definitions for a given symbol it signals an error. (This is actually a simplification, look up the One Definition Rule if you're interested in further reading).