# Undefined refrence to function

Tags: c++, undefined

I've been getting frustrated with not knowing why this happen so basically my header file doesnt want to get my function definitions from my cpp file.

I know the functions work cause I can add them to my header file itself and it works fine but it just wont work from my cpp.

**main.cpp:**

```
 #include "header.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    StackType<int> myStack;
    

    return 0;
}
```

**header.cpp**

```
#include "header.h"

using namespace std;
template<class Type>
StackType<Type>::StackType() {}
```

**header.h**

```
using namespace std;

template<class Type>
class StackType
{
public:

    StackType();

}
```

undefined reference to `StackType::StackType()'|

Comment: In `header.h`, missing a `;` to complete the class declaration.

Comment: For completeness, it's also considered a bad idea to put [`using namespace std;` in a header](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5849457/212858).

Comment: @PaulT. , sorry that was meant to already be in the question (this is not the issue) was just trying to type out my problem and forgot the ; in the code above. also as I've stated the problem doesnt lie in my header file itself since if I add the class definition in the header file then it works fine but it doenst seem to link the function to the definition in my cpp.