# I can't compile my class that use my own header file

Tags: c++, class, oop

I write my class with a header file and a cpp file but when I compile my code a get an error

myclass.h file

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

using namespace std;

class myclass{
public:
    int a;
    myclass(int);
};

#endif
```

myclass.cpp file

```
#include "myclass.h"

myclass::myclass(int a=0):a{a}{}
```

main.cpp file

```
#include<iostream>
#include "myclass.h"

using namespace std;
int main(){
    myclass a(12);
    cout<<a.a;
}
```

I get the fallowing error

```
C:\Users\Arshi\OneDrive\c++\class_test>g++ test.cpp
C:\Users\Arshi\AppData\Local\Temp\ccpDqz6v.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `myclass::myclass(int)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

what should I do

Comment: `g++ test.cpp myclass.cpp`

Comment: [You should never use `using namespace` in header files (at file scope)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5849668/1968).

Comment: If this is Visual Studio code you need to modify your tasks.json file to support compiling more than 1 source file.