# c++ why compiler cant find function overload when namespace is used?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have below four files,

```
//struct.h
#pragma once
namespace coffee {
    class MD2 {};
    class Recorder{};
    class Book{};
}


//setup.h
#pragma once
#include "struct.h"
using namespace coffee;
void wire(MD2 md2, Book book){}

//strategy.h
#pragma once
#include "struct.h"
#include "setup.h"
namespace strategy {
    using namespace coffee;
    int wire(MD2 md2, Recorder recorder) {}
    int setup2(MD2 md2, Recorder recorder, Book book) {
        wire(md2, recorder);
        wire(md2, book); //<--compiler cant find this
    }
}

//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "strategy.h"
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is before `using namespace coffee`, the program compiles fine, but after adding `namespace coffee`, the compiler cant find `wire(md2, book)`.
May I know why?

Comment: `using namespace` does not do what you think it does. Use qualified names instead.

Comment: `::wire(md2, book);`

Comment: You should not use [`using namespace` in C++ headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849457/using-namespace-in-c-headers). At least not globally, because every file you include this header in now has this `using namespace` and can't get rid of it. If the `using namespace` is inside a scope (like an inline function) it can be ok.

Comment: What is the point of using namespaces if you're `using namespace`?

Comment: You've `using namespace` at two places. One inside `strategy` and other in the header.

Answer (score 0):

As Joel pointed out in the comment to your post, you should not be [using namespace in C++ headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849457/using-namespace-in-c-headers).

To save any developer that might be working with you or with your code some headaches, I would also refrain from using `using namespace` altogether, as it will reduce readability of the code for any larger codebase.

Even for your small code example, I had to look twice to see that `Recorder` was part of `coffee`. Simple writing out `coffee::Recorder` etc., makes for more readable code and avoids annoying mistakes down the road.