# Adding Google Unit Test to makefile mantained Project

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I am trying to add some unit tests to my existing projecting. I am probably writing unit tests for the first time, so my knowledge is limited.

- Do I need to include all the header files of the project file into test file as well?

e.g if My file Addition.cpp has an include "Calculate.h" and I want to test any function Additiion.cpp. Do i need add Calculate and Addition header file

Answer (score 0):

**Most likely you don't.**

I spent some time considering your question and I think I've never seen any special rule regarding include headers and unit tests. However, based on my experience I think we can start with the following:

Include only the header you want to unit test and consider it carefully before adding a second one.

What does that means? Well let's assume you want to test your `Addition.h` API and then you craft the following on your `Test.cpp`

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

#include "Addition.h"

TEST(AdditionTest, TwoPlusTwo) {
  EXPECT_EQ(4, Add(2, 2));
}
```

You hit compile and then got this message:

```
In file included from 
Test.cpp:3:
Addition.h:4:1: error: unknown type name 'result_t'
result_t Add(int a, int b)
^
1 error generated.
```

Congratulations! Your unit test found a bug! Apparently your `Addition.h` header is not [self-contained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892043/self-sufficient-header-files-in-c-c), since it's trying to use a type - `result_t` - that the compiler does not know yet. You fix that by adding the header file that implement the type `result_t` to `Addition.h`, *not* `Test.cpp`.

Of course *some* times it's valid to add a new header to the include files of the test itself. Imagine that `Addition.h` receives an argument that is `result_t*`, and `result_t` is now an opaque type known only to the internal implementation in `Addition.cpp`. In this case, your unit might need to know a little more about `result_t` than `Addition.h`, which makes it valid to add an extra include to `Test.cpp`.

In short, in the simplest case, you add only the header you want to directly test and analyse every error with care because they just might be your first bugs.