# How to use precompiled header with dynamic library and console application?

Tags: c++

I have the problem with precompiled header. It looks somewhat like that

ftpch.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <Windows.h>
```

ftpch.cpp

```cpp
#include "ftpch.h"
```

Then I have a header file and cpp in my dll library.
test.h

```cpp
#pragma once

// DLL_EXPORT is a macro that changes for dll and console app like that:
// __declspec(dllexport) and __declspec(dllimport)

class DLL_EXPORT Test
{
    std::string foo() {return "ara ara"};
}
```

And this code compiles fine when I compile my dynamic library project, but fails to compile when I include "test.h" in my console app project and try to compile it. The error I get is:

`C2039: 'string' is not a member of 'std'`

Comment: Header order could be relevant, so you should show the console app source file. But in any case, headers should be self-contained; your `test.h` should not rely on anything that came before it to have included `<string>`.

Comment: Your console project does not use the same precompiled header file.  It has to `#include <string>` by itself to make that test.h file work.

Answer (score 0):

[Your header files should always be self-sufficient.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1892054/7431860) Include your libraries (in this case `<string>`) where you need them, everywhere you need them, and only where you need them.

If your header requires a certain library to function, include it in that file; don't reply on a different header to have included that library already, because if that different file changes, you're out of luck.

You've already got `#include` guards through `#pragma once`, so adding `#include <string.h>` to the header files that need it won't cause collision, and will also make them more maintainable and easy to interpret.